# Can't connect Android devices to MacBook Pro

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Environment Android Phone: Nokia6.
MacBook Pro Operating System: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1.
Capitan Problem: Phone could not be detected by mac or android studio.

I have searched for a long time and tried almost everything I could:

- Restart my phone or Mac or AS.
- Tried MTP or PTP.
- Tried connecting with different cables.
- Enabled Developer Options and USB debugging.
- Could be connected to Windows PC.
- Tried "add devices" and got nothing.
- Couldn't find **Vendor ID**.

Any idea about this situation would be help. Or is there a way that I can debug without USB on AS?

Comment: Have you installed nokia usb drivers for mac ?

Comment: I don't know, maybe not. How can I get one, then? Actually, when I searched for a solution, I found some links with title **Download Nokia 6 USB Drivers for Windows and Mac**. But the contents are just about **Android File Transfer** or **HandShaker**, and they don't help at all. AFT just couldn't find the device and HandShaker can only connect with my phone by WIFI(I can't debug with this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I just updated my mac to 10.13.2. And I found that my mbp could recognize my Nokia 6. It's amazing and hopefully may help others with the same problem. Update your MacOS may help.

```
$adb devices -l
List of devices attached
****************       device usb:********** product:TA-1000_00CN 
model:TA_1000 device:D1C
```